# How can I list the undocumented modules/classes/constants/methods with yardoc?

Tags: ruby, documentation, documentation-generation, yard

I have a small library of code that I am documenting with [YARD](http://yardoc.org/).  When I run the `yardoc` command, it tells me:

```
Files:          40
Modules:        14 (    0 undocumented)
Classes:        39 (    0 undocumented)
Constants:      21 (    4 undocumented)
Methods:       239 (   31 undocumented)
 88.82% documented
```

Instead of wading through all of my code to find the undocumented constants and methods, I want it to simply list the undocumented items.  Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can specifically list all undocumented objects (and their file locations) with the `--list-undoc` option.

```
yard stats --list-undoc
```

or even

```
yard --list-undoc
```

Comment: Nice!  That option wasn't listed in the `--help` output, and when I used it, yardoc said `[warn]: Unrecognized/invalid option: --list-undoc` -- but it worked anyway.  Thanks!

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer.  @Asher's is more correct.

Comment: Thanks, I've update the answer. But, Jeff, feel free to re-accept the answer if you want.

Answer (score 27):

This confused me as well. The `--list-undoc` option is actually defined under the `stats` command. Also, the command is `yard` rather than `yardoc`, which is shorthand for `yard doc`.

```
yard stats --list-undoc
```

Comment: For reference, it's actually "yard stats --list-undoc" rather than yardoc.